# Laravel [ErrorException] hash_file(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied, Windows OS

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

[Problem Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sXyw.png)

This problem occurs when try to install any package

Comment: Have a look at the [Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#configuration) section of the documentation. Some directories require specific permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error
Here is what i did to resolve the issue

1. run composer clear-cache to clear the cache.
   the difference this made was to make the error messages more elaborate.
   apparantly it was a memory limit issue so i allocated an unlimited memory in
   the php.ini file and everything worked fine.

check this link for reference.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors